# Kendo UI Grid Multi Column Hide/Show using field name

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using grouped columns...

```
columns.Group(group => group
    .HeaderTemplate("<span id='GroupHeader1'></span>")
    .Columns(info =>
    {
        info.Bound(x => x.Quantity1).Title("Qty");
        info.Bound(x => x.ECD1).Title("ECD");
    }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @data_title="Group1", @data_field="Group1" })
);

columns.Group(group => group
    .HeaderTemplate("<span id='GroupHeader1'></span>")              
    .Columns(info =>
    {
        info.Bound(x => x.Quantity2);
        info.Bound(x => x.ECD2);
    }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @data_title="Group2", @data_field="Group2" })
);
```

I can hide the multicolumn group by referencing the column order...

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.hideColumn(1);
```

BUT I need to hide/show these groups by calling them by the data-field (or id or data-title [any of which I  can set in HeaderHtmlAttributes]) as I want to allow users to reorder columns.

AND this does not work...

```
grid.hideColumn("Group1");
```

*Keep in mind that the title of the group header is dynamic too (it changes based on  a mutliselect and referencing the GroupHeader1 / GroupHeader2 Ids)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This should work according to [Kendo API Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-hideColumn). You may be using an old version of Kendo UI. Upgrade your Kendo UI to the latest one.

Comment: yes if it was a regular column, but this is a multi-column group and it does not work in this case